# ASP.NET Chart how to display all XValues

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, series

I have the chart below.  And it displays correctly but how can I get it to display all months of the year than display alternative months.  It does this for a 30 day scope where the interval displays the date at every 5 points.

I am sure this is something very easy maybe a setting I am missing?  Its standard ASP.NET Chart.

[image: Chart Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval.aspx
you can try something like :

```
myArea.AxisX.Interval=1;
```

where myArea is your main ChartArea

NB : "The Interval property of a major tick mark, grid line or label of the axis has priority over the Interval property setting of the Axis object."